# How can I bundle assets into an executable from my Game Maker-like editor?

Tags: architecture

I am attempting to implement a simple "game-maker" solution. I'm working with Visual Studio, in C#, using MonoGame. I'd like the games my editor creates to be stand-alone executables, with their art resources bundled within them so that they are not loose in a "data" folder next to the application.

I'm not sure how to implement that, though. If I create a game from my editor, how can the resulting game data be made distributable within the executable?

I'd like it so that the end result allows you to first open the editor and create and save a game, then go to that directory and run that game with its own executable.

Comment: Not exactly sure if this is within the scope of the SE; you are basically developing a tool to create games in with their own "runtime" environment. Much like RPGmaker I guess.

Comment: I agree. As written the initial question was too broad, but there's a kernel of something interesting and on-topic in there, which I've tried to emphasize. I made one fairly major assumption in the edit, which was that you didn't just want to toss these "resources" into a folder next to the executable, since that's trivial.